# Create list of shapefiles names from shapefiles in a folder, if folder does not contain shapefile type, print a statement stating this

Tags: python, shapefile, file-path, if-else, files

I am creating a list of shapefiles names from files in a folder:

```
items = os.listdir(r'E:/folder/test')

print('checking directory...')
print('your files are: ')
print()
filenames = []
for names in items:
    if names.endswith(".shp"):
        filenames.append(names)
        print(filenames)
        print()
    else:
        print("there are no files ending with .shp in your folder")
```

If there are no files in the folder that are .shp files, I want the if/else conditional to print a statement saying this. My code is currently doing both, any solution?

Comment: There does not appear to be a true GIS component to this question. Doing this for `*.shp` files is near identical to doing it for `*.txt` files and so I think it should be researched at [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the check for no files out of the loop

```
items = os.listdir(r'E:/folder/test')

print('checking directory...')
print('your files are: ')
print()
filenames = []

for names in items:
    if names.endswith(".shp"):
        filenames.append(names)
        print(filenames)

if not filenames: 
    print("there are no files ending with .shp in your folder")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the NO statement inside the loop for every file that isn't a .shp. That should be left to the end, after you have checked. You are also printing the name of the file if it is a .shp, but that wasn't in your question.

1. Get a list of files
2. Filter the list by type (lower case in case they end with 'SHP')
3. Output results

   ```
   files = os.listdir(r'E:/folder/test')
   files = [f for f in files if f.lower().endswith('shp')]
   if len(files)==0:
       print("there are no files ending with .shp in your folder")
   else:
       print('There are {} shapefiles in your folder'.format(len(files)))
       for f in files:
           print(f)
   ```